# upload file move out of public_html folder in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i my web application i need to upload files out of public_html in Code Igniter frame work.

my root structure is

```
home/user/
    .cpanel
    .gem
    .htpasswds
    .trash
    access-logs
    bin
    STORE_FILE
    etc
    mail
    php
    public_ftp
    public_html
    tmp
    www
```

how to upload file or move from my public html folder to STORE_FILE location by use of php or in code igniter. Is there any function to make ease this work ? 
and how to call in main website?

Answer (score 0):

use this controller function target your form here

```
   function do_upload()
   {
    //set your configuration here

            //upload path which it contains write permission
    $config['upload_path'] = '/var/www/uploads/';

    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';       

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('form_field_name'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: i got something ok. but in my cpanel, www and public_html folders are same. i have to access the file in STORE_FILE folder. I tried  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] then i got /home/paasamal/public_html. i need to remove public_html from above structure . is there any function to solve this. i found one way to use from public_html/application/controller/test.php to access STORE_FILE is  ../../STORE_FILE. i want to short out this.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the config for the upload:

```
$upload_config['upload_path'] = '/var/www/';      #when initializing the upload in CI
```